# how to make sure that two or more concurrent connections do not exceed a certain range WebApi core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a Table with a field that contains the the quantity of how many times a certain table data must be "created". A simple query to make sure how many times this table was created wont solve, because someone at the same time could do the same thing and add another unwanted row.

I was thinking about make the method synchronous but since I'm using WebApi it must be asynchronous.

Or using procedure to before the row be created make sure that the range still less than the table count. I'm using WebApi Core with Entity Framework.

Comment: You can use Transaction while inserting the record.

Comment: Try `using(var transaction=_context.Database.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.Serializable)){  /*... */ }`

Comment: @itminus so inside I could insert the data knowing that it wont be two connections at the same time ?

Comment: Not "wont be two connections at the same time", but will produce the same effect as the serial execution.

Comment: See also [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-transaction-isolation-level-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)